# Java geoip2 java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, file, geoip2

I use geoip2 to determine the country by ip. During development and testing of the code, I have no problems, but when I run the compiled archive, I encounter a java.io.FileNotFoundException exception. I understand that this is because the path to the file is absolute, and in the archive it changes. Question: How do I need to change my code so that even from the archive I can access the file?

```
   public static String getCountryByIp(String ip) throws Exception {
    File database = new File(URLDecoder.decode(GeoUtils.class.getResource("/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb").getFile(),"UTF-8"));


    DatabaseReader dbReader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    CountryResponse response = dbReader.country(ipAddress);

    return response.getCountry().getName();
}
```

[test.war/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsHNz.png)
[test.war/WEB-INF/classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMoLJ.png)

Comment: Whether it is plain java code or any framework your using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\general\Desktop\test\target\test.war!\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb

Comment: Are you sure GeoLite2-Country.mmdb is part of war file ? whats the relartive location in the war file ? is it src/main/resources/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb ?

Comment: In the project directory: src \ main \ resources \ GeoLite2-Country.mmdb;
In the archive: test.war \ WEB-INF \ classes \ GeoLite2-Country.mmdb;

Comment: I am pretty sure the GeoLite2-Country.mmdb is not in your war file or else it would never have thrown java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\general\Desktop\test\target\test.war!\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb

Comment: Attached to the post image of the archive structure